# What's the difference between agent.add() and conv.ask() on dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can someone please explain to me what the difference between agent.add() and conv.ask() in dialogflow is when it is appropriate to use each one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are building Google Assistant app then you use `conv.ask` otherwise use `agent.add`.

In Google Assistant, if you want to keep the conversation alive, you will use `conv.ask` and if you want to end the conversation you will use `conv.close`. 
In other Dialogflow based conversation, you use `agent.end` to end the converstaion.